# Products not showing on category page after reindex in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3

I have set up the Magento 2.3.2 website on the Nexcess Cloud Hosting server. I have transfer all the files and database from my localhost. Everything is working fine except for the Indexing process. Whenever I used the CLI command

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

All the products showing from the category pages stops and displayed a message that there is no product matching. I have debugged the issue and found that after run the command "catalog_product_index_price" table get empty and there is no data. when I import the local data in this table all products displayed again. is it the hosting issue OR should I need to debug the cod more

Can you anyone please how can I debug why to reindex process not working properly.

you can see the CLI command that indexing process not taking any time for execution

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research and full database debug. I have found that the table "inventory_stock_1" View was not created when transferring the database from local to the cloud and it was a permission access issue.

After added this table manually without using user and password everything is working perfectly
Thanks